# Implementing Rotation In 2D Texture on its center

Tags: directx-11

I am still learning Directx 11.

I am following the Rastertek Directx 11 Tutorial 11, I was able to render a 2D texture on the screen, here is the link to the tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut11.html

I am wondering how I could rotate this texture in the center of its axis.  I don't know where to begin.  I tried using a z rotation matrix to get it to rotate, but it does not rotate around its center, it rotates around somewhere else.

My guess is we have to add the rotation in GraphicsClass::Render

```
bool GraphicsClass::Render(float rotation)
{
    D3DXMATRIX worldMatrix, viewMatrix, projectionMatrix, orthoMatrix;
    bool result;


    // Clear the buffers to begin the scene.
    m_D3D->BeginScene(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Generate the view matrix based on the camera's position.
    m_Camera->Render();

    // Get the world, view, projection, and ortho matrices from the camera and d3d objects.
    m_Camera->GetViewMatrix(viewMatrix);
    m_D3D->GetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);
    m_D3D->GetProjectionMatrix(projectionMatrix);
    m_D3D->GetOrthoMatrix(orthoMatrix);

    // Turn off the Z buffer to begin all 2D rendering.
    m_D3D->TurnZBufferOff();

    // Put the bitmap vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    result = m_Bitmap->Render(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), 100, 100);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Render the bitmap with the texture shader.
    result = m_TextureShader->Render(m_D3D->GetDeviceContext(), m_Bitmap->GetIndexCount(), worldMatrix, viewMatrix, orthoMatrix, m_Bitmap->GetTexture());
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Turn the Z buffer back on now that all 2D rendering has completed.
    m_D3D->TurnZBufferOn();

    // Present the rendered scene to the screen.
    m_D3D->EndScene();

    return true;
}

bool BitmapClass::Render(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, int positionX, int positionY)
{
    bool result;


    // Re-build the dynamic vertex buffer for rendering to possibly a different location on the screen.
    result = UpdateBuffers(deviceContext, positionX, positionY);
    if(!result)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Put the vertex and index buffers on the graphics pipeline to prepare them for drawing.
    RenderBuffers(deviceContext);

    return true;
}


bool BitmapClass::UpdateBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext, int positionX, int positionY)
{
    float left, right, top, bottom;
    VertexType* vertices;
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
    VertexType* verticesPtr;
    HRESULT result;


    // If the position we are rendering this bitmap to has not changed then don't update the vertex buffer since it
    // currently has the correct parameters.
    if((positionX == m_previousPosX) && (positionY == m_previousPosY))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If it has changed then update the position it is being rendered to.
    m_previousPosX = positionX;
    m_previousPosY = positionY;

    // Calculate the screen coordinates of the left side of the bitmap.
    left = (float)((m_screenWidth / 2) * -1) + (float)positionX;

    // Calculate the screen coordinates of the right side of the bitmap.
    right = left + (float)m_bitmapWidth;

    // Calculate the screen coordinates of the top of the bitmap.
    top = (float)(m_screenHeight / 2) - (float)positionY;

    // Calculate the screen coordinates of the bottom of the bitmap.
    bottom = top - (float)m_bitmapHeight;

    // Create the vertex array.
    vertices = new VertexType[m_vertexCount];
    if(!vertices)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Load the vertex array with data.
    // First triangle.
    vertices[0].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, top, 0.0f);  // Top left.
    vertices[0].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    vertices[1].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, bottom, 0.0f);  // Bottom right.
    vertices[1].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    vertices[2].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, bottom, 0.0f);  // Bottom left.
    vertices[2].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 1.0f);

    // Second triangle.
    vertices[3].position = D3DXVECTOR3(left, top, 0.0f);  // Top left.
    vertices[3].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(0.0f, 0.0f);

    vertices[4].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, top, 0.0f);  // Top right.
    vertices[4].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 0.0f);

    vertices[5].position = D3DXVECTOR3(right, bottom, 0.0f);  // Bottom right.
    vertices[5].texture = D3DXVECTOR2(1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Lock the vertex buffer so it can be written to.
    result = deviceContext->Map(m_vertexBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get a pointer to the data in the vertex buffer.
    verticesPtr = (VertexType*)mappedResource.pData;

    // Copy the data into the vertex buffer.
    memcpy(verticesPtr, (void*)vertices, (sizeof(VertexType) * m_vertexCount));

    // Unlock the vertex buffer.
    deviceContext->Unmap(m_vertexBuffer, 0);

    // Release the vertex array as it is no longer needed.
    delete [] vertices;
    vertices = 0;

    return true;
}

void BitmapClass::RenderBuffers(ID3D11DeviceContext* deviceContext)
{
    unsigned int stride;
    unsigned int offset;


    // Set vertex buffer stride and offset.
    stride = sizeof(VertexType); 
    offset = 0;

    // Set the vertex buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    deviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Set the index buffer to active in the input assembler so it can be rendered.
    deviceContext->IASetIndexBuffer(m_indexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

    // Set the type of primitive that should be rendered from this vertex buffer, in this case triangles.
    deviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    return;
}
```

How can I rotate the texture around the center of the texture?

Comment: Note that those tutorials are a bit dated w.r.t. to the utility code, i.e. it's using D3DXmath which is ancient. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/26/introducing-directxmath/) and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). Doing simple Sprite rendering you should just use something like ``SpriteBatch`` in the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite. It's a bit more subtle than that. Let me go over the basics of transformations first.

In DirectX, and 3D graphics in general, transformations are typically represented by a 4x4 affine transformation matrix that does three successive geometric transformations: one from local space to world space (world matrix), one from world space to camera-centric space (view matrix), and one from camera-centric space to "homogenous clip space" (projection matrix). You'll generally hear this referred to as the WVP (**W**orld-**V**iew-**P**rojection) matrix.

The single transformation matrix is created by the multiplication of each of the individual transformation matrices that make it up. This multiplication process **is not** commutative, meaning matrix AB is not the same as matrix BA. In the context of transformations, AB applies transform A and then transform B, whereas BA applies transform B and then transform A. If A is a rotation of 45 degrees about Z, and b is a translation of 3 units along X, AB will rotate the object by 45 degrees and place it 3 units to the right, whereas BA will move the object 3 units right and swing it around by 45 degrees, as though it was connected to the origin by a bar. The image below shows this graphically.

[image: RxT vs. TxR]

Now that we've dealt with the basics, let's move on to the actual code.

Looking it over, I can see that your initial assumption of the problem was both right and wrong - you figured out what the issue was, but misinterpreted the cause.

First major issue - your geometry is specified entirely in world space. This is fine if the geometry is never going to move, but the whole point of this question is to get said geometry to move, so...

To fix this, construct your shape in the simplest way possible: centered around the origin, with sides of length 1. This changes the four corners to be the following, assuming +X is to the right, +Y is up, and +Z is out (into the screen): (-0.5, 0.5, 0), (0.5, 0.5, 0), (-0.5, -0.5, 0), (0.5, -0.5, 0). These represent the top left, top right, bottom left, and bottom right corners, respectively.

This also allows you to create the vertex buffer once in your constructor, and never need to update it again afterwards, even if the size of the image changes during runtime.

Second, because of the original specification of the geometry was in world space already, we didn't need a real world matrix. Now that our geometry is a unit square around a local origin, we do. To get an image the same size as the source bitmap, we make a scaling matrix that scales by `m_bitmapWidth` on the X axis and `m_bitmapHeight` on the Y axis. We then multiply it by a rotation matrix around the Z axis to spin it, and finally multiply it by a translation matrix to move it to `positionX` and `positionY`. We can rewrite `UpdateBuffers` as follows:

```
bool BitmapClass::UpdateBuffers(int positionX, int positionY, float rotationAngle)
{
    D3DXMATRIX scaling, rotation, translation, worldMatrix;
    // If the position we are rendering this bitmap to has not changed,
    // don't update the world matrix since it currently has the correct 
    // parameters.
    if((positionX == m_previousPosX) && (positionY == m_previousPosY))
    {
        return true;
    }
    // If it has changed then update the position it is being rendered to.
    m_previousPosX = positionX;
    m_previousPosY = positionY;

    // scale, rotate, and translate our unit square
    D3DXMatrixScaling(&scaling, m_bitmapWidth, m_bitmapHeight, 1);
    D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&rotation, rotationAngle);
    D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation, positionX, positionY, 0);

    //Now concatenate all the transformations together,
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&worldMatrix, &scaling, &rotation);
    D3DXMatrixMultiply(&worldMatrix, &worldMatrix, &translation);

    // And tell D3D this is our new world matrix.
    m_D3D->SetWorldMatrix(worldMatrix);

    return true;
}
```

The final edit is to remove the call to `UpdateBuffers` in `BitmapClass::Render`, and make the call prior to calling `GetWorldMatrix`. This will ensure the rendering process uses the proper transformation matrix.